# Time sensitive questions

Tags: discussion, questions

I know it is the philosophy of SO that whoever who is asking a question do his/her homework first and put down a reasonable amount of research first.

But I want to know your point of view regarding a case when a question is time sensitive.

For example a production bug which can have a dozen of causes. Lets call them Cause 1-10.

In such a case, while studying cause 3(for example SQL Server parameter conflict), should the asker the question put it in SO(when he is positive it is not duplicate)? Assuming in this case he can't afford to spend more time to study the cause.

All Feedbacks are greatly appreciated.

Comment: How is that time-sensitive nature of the issue relevant to the actual question? Do you mean that a user need to get an answer within a time-frame?

Comment: This reads like *"If the poster needs an answer in a hurry and doesn't have time to do investigation themselves, can they still post it?"*. Is that correct?

Comment: @JonW, Yes almost. They do some investigation themselves but the time they spent is minimal.

Comment: The answer to this question is better Project Management, not crappy SO questions.

Comment: OK, assume questions are not necessarily crappy, since they are coming from an expert and not a newbie.

Comment: I'm going to call 10 items an *asker's dozen* from now on.

Comment: `1-10 = -9`. To get to cause 3, OP did `x = |-9-3| = 12`

Comment: Using little time as an excuse isn't our problem; it's yours.

Comment: Other people's deadlines are none of our concern. It's that simple.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Sure, they can post it.

But they can't:

1. Expect a swift response from the community, who after all are volunteering their time.
2. Expect a good reaction from the community being told "and hurry up, I don't have time for this".

Have you ever heard the saying - "poor planning on your part does not constitute an Emergency on my part."? That's the general feeling the community gets when a post asking for speed comes up.

---

It is much better to simply post the question, without any expectation of an answer or a quick one, at that. The urgency of getting an answer is not relevant to the question and should be left out.

Comment: It took you almost 10 minutes to post this answer. This is unacceptable!

Comment: @JonW :) haha. Now that's yet another scenario. An As#le in rush to get answer to his urgent question.

Comment: @JonW - You didn't pay enough for it to be instantaneous.

Comment: @JoeTatavaran - Well... yeah. People answering questions also have jobs. It is fair to expect someone with a problem to give it their best effort before posting it.

Comment: Totally agreed. Urgency of the question is only the problem of the person who asks it, not others. It is very rude to push others for your own problem :)

Comment: @JoeTatavaran: I'd argue that you "pushed the urgency" by asking a question *at all* when you could have tried it yourself in a few minutes. You didn't explicitly state the urgency, but you basically didn't do the normal due diligence expected, and then blamed that on your production emergency.

Answer (score 8):

The fact that your question is urgent to you in no way changes the standards of this site.  You don't get to not do your homework, or not take the time to write a quality question, or not have to follow any of the other rules just because your problem needs to be solved quickly.

The standards apply regardless.  If you're able to do the proper research, and write a quality question, and follow all of the other guidelines/rules even though your question is very time sensitive, then great, if not, it will not get any special treatment.